# What's the simplest way to 'cut' specific arguments passed to bash script

Tags: bash

I have two scripts: aaa and bbb.

Each script has some arguments. Argument can be string, number or has format like --some-action or like --name=foo.

Script aaa execute script bbb. Some arguments for bbb generated in aaa, but some arguments I can manually add from executing script aaa like:

```
$ aaa "arguments for aaa" "arguments for bbb"
```

I can not pass to bbb all arguments of aaa, because bbb has control to unknown arguments.

I do not know how extract "arguments for bbb" in aaa script. Can anybody help me?

So, I want to execute in aaa:

```
bbb "some arguments from aaa" "arguments for bbb"
```

Comment: How exactly will the arguments be laid out? Will they actually be in quotes like your example: `aaa "arguments for aaa" "arguments for bbb"`? Or would it be more like this: `aaa -a -b -c -d -e -f` where only `-d -e -f` are used in `bbb`?

Comment: Typically `bbb "$@"` will pass the arguments supplied to `aaa` along.

Comment: @Peschkem second way: aaa -a -b -c -d -e -f. Now I use argument-separator to detect where arguments for bbb started. Now I'm use way: for arg in "$@"; do case ... and increment argument index (argIdx) to detect, where first argument for bbb. I'm use ${@:$argIdx} at finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse all arguments in the `aaa` script with **[getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt)** and then pass them to your script as needed.

I adjustet an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180880/how-to-support-both-short-and-long-options-at-the-same-time-in-bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS=`getopt -o abcdef -l argument-for-both: -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) OPT_a=true; shift;;
        -d) ARG_B="$ARG_B -b"; shift;;
        --argument-for-both)
            OPT_argument_for_both=true
            ARG_B="$ARG_B --argument-for-both"
            shift;;
    esac
done

# aaa
if [[ $OPT_a ]] ; then do_something ; fi
if [[ $OPT_argument_for_both ]] ; then do_something_else ; fi

# bbb
bbb $ARG_B
```